# CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider giving blank image

Tags: ios

Please check this code and help me out,,,

```
CGImageRef cRef = CGImageRetain(im.CGImage);

NSData* pixelData = (NSData*) CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(cRef));

// return pointer to data
unsigned char* pixelBytes = (unsigned char *)[pixelData bytes];

// step through char data
for(int k = 0; k < [pixelData length]; k += 4) {
  // change accordingly
  pixelBytes[k] = pixelBytes[k];
  pixelBytes[k+1] = pixelBytes[k+1];
  pixelBytes[k+2] = pixelBytes[k+2];
  pixelBytes[k+3] = 255;
}

NSData* newPixelData = [NSData dataWithBytes:pixelBytes length:[pixelData length]];
CFDataRef imgData = (CFDataRef)pixelData;
CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imgData);
CGImageRef throughCGImage = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, YES, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:throughCGImage];
NSLog(@"newImage: %@", newImage);
```

Some data is coming but it is not getting added to UIImageView..it is showing blank.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 0)

You're mutating immutable data, which should be undefined behavior.

Problem 1)

Anyways, a PNG is a real file format, not a bitmap blob with a fixed sample format. PNG can represent images in many ways - your programs just overwrites good data.